# Prefer Angular 1.4 or 2.0 for new web application?

Tags: angularjs, mvc

I see that this question had been asked previously too, but that was a different timeframe.

We are starting with new web application and want to make a decision between AngularJS 2 and 1.4. Our other technology stack includes, ASP.Net 5, MVC6, EF7, Bootstrap 4, Web API, Google Maps V3 and other Google Api's.

The Key features of our application is Driving log(trips), Trip Route mapping, Fleet Management, subscription module, reports module.

As AngularJS 2 is still in Beta version and till they last updated, they haven't have a date for publishing a stable version of AngularJS2.

- So should i go for AngularJS2 now? or should wait till its stable version (if its not later that Q1 2016) or should i start with mix version of Angular 1 and 2 and upgrade it later?
- Also, how fit Angular 2 is with my technology stack and feature list?
- Anyone having idea what could be the probable date for Angular 2 release date, will help the cause.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: How critical is your application? When is your target production release date?

Comment: We have already started with the UI wireframes and planning to start development from Feb 2016 and proposed dates for release is in Q3-2016.

Comment: Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)

Comment: Thanks Izzy for your comment, but that's the same reason i have mentioned what other  technology stack i am using and what are the basic feature list my application has, so that to identify which Angular suits best with my requirement and current tech stack.